# Manifest Merger Probleme

Tags: android

I'm using gamemaker studio 1, and I just added a gameanalytics extension, then I started to get errors in compiling.

This is the error:

```
com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg:processReleaseManifestZ:\com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:60:1-114 Error:
Element meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version at AndroidManifest.xml:60:1-114 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:56:2-117
Z:\com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
Validation failed, exiting


See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

:com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg:processReleaseManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

My android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg" android:versionCode="1001007" android:versionName="1.1.7" android:installLocation="auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:allowBackup="false">
    <!-- This is the androidmanifest.xml used as the basis for building game .apk's from Studio -->
    <!-- uses here -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" /> -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
    <!--   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>  -->
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:largeScreens="true" />
    <!-- application -->
    <application android:name="com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg.RunnerApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" tools:replace="android:label">
        <activity android:name="com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg.RunnerActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" tools:replace="android:label">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg.RunnerPreferenceActivity" android:label="@string/menu_settings"></activity>
        <!-- services -->
        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="9683000" tools:replace="android:value" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- activities here -->
        <!-- receivers here -->
        <receiver android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".PushLocalAlarmReceiver" />
        <!-- This is XPeria Play specific, we have decided to make this standard though for all applications, just in case -->
        <meta-data android:name="xperiaplayoptimized_content" android:resource="@string/xperiaplayoptimized_content" />
        <meta-data android:name="game_display_name" android:resource="@string/app_name" />
        <!--    <meta-data android:name="game_icon" android:resource="@drawable/icon" />
     Removing due to following warning:
     Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration (except for version qualifiers, e.g. '-v21'.) Found variation in hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi
     -->
        <!-- meta-data here -->
        <meta-data android:value="1" android:name="YYUse24Bit" />
        <meta-data android:value="0" android:name="OrientLandscape" />
        <meta-data android:value="-1" android:name="OrientPortrait" />
        <meta-data android:value="0" android:name="OrientLandscapeFlipped" />
        <meta-data android:value="0" android:name="OrientPortraitFlipped" />
        <meta-data android:value="2" android:name="SplashscreenTime" />
        <meta-data android:value="4" android:name="SleepMargin" />
        <meta-data android:name="YYHostIP" android:value="127.0.0.1" />
        <meta-data android:name="YYHostPort" android:value="51268" />
        <meta-data android:name="YYNumExtensionClasses" android:value="4" />
        <meta-data android:name="YYExtensionClass0" android:value="GooglePlayServicesExtension" />
        <meta-data android:name="GoogleMobileAds_Banner" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="GoogleMobileAds_MRect" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="GoogleMobileAds_Full_Banner" android:value="3" />
        <meta-data android:name="GoogleMobileAds_Leaderboard" android:value="4" />
        <meta-data android:name="GoogleMobileAds_Skyscraper" android:value="5" />
        <meta-data android:name="GooglePlayServices_SUCCESS" android:value="0" />
        <meta-data android:name="GooglePlayServices_SERVICE_MISSING" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="GooglePlayServices_SERVICE_UPDATING" android:value="18" />
        <meta-data android:name="GooglePlayServices_SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="GooglePlayServices_SERVICE_DISABLED" android:value="3" />
        <meta-data android:name="GooglePlayServices_SERVICE_INVALID" android:value="9" />
        <meta-data android:name="YYExtensionClass1" android:value="GooglePlayLicensingAsExt" />
        <meta-data android:name="YYExtensionClass3" android:value="GameAnalyticsExt" />
        <meta-data android:name="GA_ERRORSEVERITY_DEBUG" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="GA_ERRORSEVERITY_INFO" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="GA_ERRORSEVERITY_WARNING" android:value="3" />
        <meta-data android:name="GA_ERRORSEVERITY_ERROR" android:value="4" />
        <meta-data android:name="GA_ERRORSEVERITY_CRITICAL" android:value="5" />
        <meta-data android:name="GA_RESOURCEFLOWTYPE_SOURCE" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="GA_RESOURCEFLOWTYPE_SINK" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="GA_GENDER_MALE" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="GA_GENDER_FEMALE" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="GA_PROGRESSIONSTATUS_START" android:value="1" />
        <meta-data android:name="GA_PROGRESSIONSTATUS_COMPLETE" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="GA_PROGRESSIONSTATUS_FAIL" android:value="3" />
        <meta-data android:value="true" android:name="EnablePushNotification" />
        <meta-data android:value="pid1011672074512" android:name="PushNotificationID" />
        <meta-data android:name="IsBuiltAsYoYoRunner" android:value="Yes" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Build Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dragonpirates.trollforpubg"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("C:/Users/mootaz/AppData/Local/GameMaker-Studio/trollforpubg.keystore")
            storePassword "21313943"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "21313943"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    splits { 
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "armeabi-v7a"
            universalApk false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/ini4j-0.5.2.jar')



    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'

    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile project(":library")

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1'

    compile fileTree(dir: "elibs", include: ["*.jar"])
}
```

I tried to fix this problem for days and I still didn't found any solution!
And in the extension documentation it says that I need to have *Google Play Service 9.4.0* (how can I know if I have it or not? Also I can't find it in the SDK manager!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finnaly found the solution for this !
first problem there are both extensions ( google play services & gameanalytics ) have same application level :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  android:value="9683000"  tools:replace="android:value" />
```

second problem  gameanalytics uses google play services 10.5.0 instead of 9.4.0 as you can see in the gradle box

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.5.0'
```

### FIX :

1 - remove this line from gameanalytics application level :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  android:value="9683000"  tools:replace="android:value" />
```

2- delete everyting writen in the gradle Box and replace it with this lane :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0'
```

- i will add some screenshots to show where to do this exactly .[screen of gamenalytics extansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6Bg3.png) [screen of google play services extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVe18.png)
hope you find this helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your build.gradle file on dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.4.'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
```

instead of

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'
```

Comment: Hi man , I changed them using notepad and saved the file , but after compiling i get the same error , so i reopened the file and i found that thay changed back to 9.6.1 ! ( btw im using game maker and thats my android configure : Min SDK : 15 , Target SDK :25 , Compile SDL:25 , Build Tools : 27.0.0 , support lib 25.3.1 )

Comment: EDIT : i finnaly found how to change them with gamemaker , but sadly i still get the same error !

Comment: sorry then, i've never used gamemaker before :/
must be a gamemaker error, you can also try to use another API or another IDE